# C++ DLL LPCTSTR to C# string

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to get string from C++ DLL to C#.
It outputs incorrect symbols - {栠搂珯獲긋ݳݳ贈琹玴ɡݳ⻜}

Here is my code:
C++ DLL

```
_declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall myClass(LPCTSTR& z)
{
    z = _T("Test String");
    return 0;
}
```

My C# code reading C++ DLL:

```
[DllImport("ecrClassDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern void myClass(StringBuilder z);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder z = new StringBuilder();
    myClass(z);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you defined the `UNICODE` macro in C++, so that `_T` outputs `wchar_t` data, and `LPCTSTR` means `const wchar_t*`. That's what `CharSet.Unicode` expects. By the way, if you don't intend to support an ANSI version too, I wouldn't bother with all this `_T` stuff and just use Unicode everywhere, the code will be simpler.

Also, your C++ function returns an `int`, but your C# function expects a `void`. You have a mismatch there (unless you intended to set `PreserveSig` to `false`).

On the C# side, when you provide a `StringBuilder`, it means you provide a buffer to the C++ side, and you expect it to fill that buffer. The correct usage would be something like this:

```cpp
_declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall myClass(LPCTSTR z, int zSize)
{
    _tcscpy_s(z, zSize, _T("Test String"));
    return 0;
}
```

```cs
[DllImport("ecrClassDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int myClass(StringBuilder z, int zSize);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder z = new StringBuilder(256);
    myClass(z, z.Capacity);
}
```

But your code returns a pointer to a static string, which the marshaller doesn't expect here.

If you'd like to keep your C++ code as-is, you could try this instead:

```
[DllImport("ecrClassDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int myClass(out string z);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string z;
    myClass(out z);
}
```

I admit I didn't test it, but it should work as this C# signature matches the C++ signature.

If everything fails, you could try to marshal the data by yourself:

```
[DllImport("ecrClassDll.dll")]
static extern unsafe int myClass(void** z);

static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    void* z;
    myClass(&z);
    var str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(new IntPtr(z));
}
```

Comment: I already tried out string, but my console app dies without error and thats all..
If i include pdb file it returns "Unhandled exception at 0x7746ED0B (ntdll.dll) in CallDLL.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x774A4270)." and string in C#

Comment: *Heap corruption*, means *signature mismatch*... Hmm, you could try `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` but I don't think it'll change much. I've added a 3rd approach to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I figured out that in my case "out string" works only in 4.0 framework or lower, x86 and only in release mode(original DLL where I needed your help is not mine).

Comment: That's weird. Working in x86 only is fine (your C++ DLL is x86), but not working in 4.5+ and in debug mode is a red flag for me, I can"t think of any reason something like that would happen...