# Passing a StringBuilder and getting back a result from a c++ dll to c#

Tags: c#, c++, character-encoding, calling-convention

I have the following code in C#:

```
[DllImport("ClassLibrary2.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GetString(StringBuilder buffer, ref int bufferSize);

 void get()
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    int bufferSize = 32;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);
    GetString(buffer, ref bufferSize);
    string currentString = buffer.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(currentString);
}
```

and the following in c++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetString(char* buffer, int* bufferSize){
    MD5 md5;
    char *returnChar = md5.digestFile(buffer);
    cout << returnChar << endl;
    strcpy(buffer, returnChar);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work.. I've tried many many many things and neither seem to work. This is probably the only thing that doesn't crash my C# program directly so I am left to using it. I need to get a string but I can do with a `StringBuilder` too.

Yes, my program does work as the `cout<<returnChar<<endl;` works and displays what I need to see.

Yes, I have tried marshaling it using the calling convention `stdcall` and many others... what is the simplest way to pass and get a string back?

Comment: Try this: `GetString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder buffer, ref int bufferSize)`, or use `CharSet.Ansi`

Comment: Your example won't work because StringBuilder doesn't implicitly convert into a char* when calling a C++ method. Looks like Lucas has provided an example you could try.

Comment: Just tried it out ... unfortunately i get an error again : Unable to find method getstring in ClassLibrary2.dll

Comment: I've noticed that @LucasTrzesniewski has answered a similar question before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262991/c-dll-lpctstr-to-c-sharp-string?lq=1, did you try the 3rd example in his answer?

Comment: It gives me an error and i can`t figure out how to solve this

Comment: An "md5.digestFile()" function requires you to pass the path to a file, you are not doing that.  Easiest way to see this yourself is noting that you use OpenFileDialog but you never actually use the selected file in your code.  You'll get *something* out of the function anyway, even though the function failed, albeit that "an error" gives hope.  Shopping around for a more reliable implementation would be wise,  use the System.Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng class instead.

Answer (score 1):

`CharSet = CharSet.Auto` is not compatible with  `void GetString(char* buffer, int* bufferSize)`. Use `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` to make it work. `CharSet.Auto` is only for importing system library functions that exist in both Ansi and Unicode variants and having .net pick the right one to call.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do this?

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(byte[] input)
{
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(input);

    // Convert to hex string
    return string.Join("", hash.Select(h => h.ToString("X2")));
}
```

And call it with `var hash = CalculateMD5Hash(File.ReadAllBytes("path-goes-here"))`?